# Is my table partitioned correctly based on my datetime column?

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning, partition

I have a **partitioned table with a datetime column** that looks like this:

[image]

The datetime column includes the date, hours, minutes, and seconds, and **every row has a different datetime column** (the difference is mainly in the seconds, minutes, and hours)

The table is partitioned on the datetime column like so:

[image]

My question is - **since every row has a different datetime column, and the datetime is not rounded to hours but instead includes seconds and minutes, is my table still partitioned correctly?**

So if the rows had datetimes like:

```
2021-11-19T01:00:00
2021-11-19T02:00:00
2021-11-19T03:00:00
...
```

then I'm pretty sure the table will be partitioned correctly, but instead the rows have datetimes like:

```
2021-11-19T01:25:01
2021-11-19T02:11:50
2021-11-19T03:00:21
...
```

Is that a problem? Is my table partitioned correctly despite the seconds and minutes (which cause all rows to have different datetime values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all fine and your table is partitioned in the way you want it to be.

What you're describing is exactly the purpose of the `Partitioned by` column. BigQuery is effectively replacing the minutes and seconds with 0's for you when it chooses a partition for each record.

To be extra clear, if you pass in `2021-11-19T02:11:50` then it will be placed in the `2021-11-19T02:00:00` partition.

If you want to see the partitions to verify this then you can run:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM `<PROJECT>.<DATASET>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
WHERE table_name = '<TABLE_NAME>'
```